# Postmessage example from console cross-domain

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I just try to receive postmessage from other window in my browser.
So I opened 2 sites: example1.com and example2.com. And I opened chrome inspectors on both tabs.

In one inspector I placed code:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(){console.log('FIRED')})
```

In second one:

```
window.postMessage('Hello!', '*');
```

No fire if they're different tabs and even same domains. It only fires if it's the same chrome inspector.

So what I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can't arbitrarily post across tabs. The [`postMessage` method is on `window`'s prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), so you need a valid `Window` to post against.

If you are posting to the current window's parent or a child (and can use `window.parent` or get the child frame's context`) or have opened a new window and still hold a reference to it, then you can post across frames or tabs. You cannot just post to an arbitrary tab open in the same browser, however, as that would be a serious security issue.